# Есть сайт интернет-магазина, работающего на 1c-bitrix

Tags: 1с, битрикс

На нём есть каталог товаров с характеристиками. Помимо характеристик нужно добавить описание к каждому товару внизу страницы.

Вся сложность в том, как это сделать. В админ панели каталога товаров не вижу возможности добавить поле для описания модели, при редактировании через сайт можно, открыв сам код странички (в html или php режиме) поправить, но увы, добавив описание, которое отображается корректно, это описание становится описанием всей группы товаров (т.е видно под каждой страничкой с товаром).

Как сделать, что бы на 1 товар приходилось 1 описание?

Кто-нибудь может подсказку дать?

Comment: Сорри за офтоп, но 1С-Битрикс это платная CMS. Так неужели у них нет технической поддержки клиентов?

Comment: Я просто работаю с ним, не я его разрабатывала, он не продленный по тех. поддержке. Для таких клиентов битрикс отвечает в течении трех недель и то не всегда).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это все настраивается в админке. как и по всем твоим вопросам, советую почитать мануалы по 1С битрикс, там все описано как и что добавлять.

Код открыт у битрикса, не надо тут гнать, все модули его имеют нормальный код, а вот ядро-да зашифровано!

Все настраивается в админке, повторюсь. И работать с ним нужно аккуратно. ибо система мне никогда не нравилась, хоть её так изрядно пиарят!

Могу за отд-ю пл-у помочь настроить 1с-Битрикс.

Answer (score 0):

Могу ошибаться, но у Битрикс не открытый исходный код, поэтому полагаю, что вам будет крайне сложно что-либо изменить самому. А если и можно, то тут нужны определенные знания или нанимать профессионалов, а это тоже деньги. Поэтому, уж лучше проплатить продление тех.поддержки.